# Apache2 not picking up the correct index.html by default

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I'm setting up a webserver. I've added one virtual host to test it out. When I browse to the IP address of the server I see the default Apache welcome page as expected. I've added an example URL to my host file and I have a vhost for that domain set up in the webserver.  I've placed an index.html file in the root of that vhost.  Now, if I browse to that url I still see the default Apache welcome page. However, if I add 'index.html' to the url then I get the page I'm expecting to see. I've Googled this (and I'm still looking just now) but haven't been able to come up with an answer to this.  Has anyone seen this before?

I'm running apache2 under Debian.

As requested, here is my vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/home/me/www/example.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you show us your vhost files ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/25250/apache2-displaying-root-index-html-instead-of-virtualhosts-index-html). Turns out it wasn't a fault, just that my browser cache needed to be refreshed.